# How to set activity result without finishing activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-intent, onactivityresult

I have a `fragment(MyFragment)` from where I am showing a popup chooser view as an `Intent Activity (PopupActivity)`.

I need to pass chosen arguments to the `fragment (MyFragment)` without calling `finish()` on `Activity (PopupActivity)`

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.putExtra(intentKey, chosenValue)
setResult(ConstantIntentStatusCode.popupResult, intent)
```

This code works, when I call `finish()` on the PopupActivity. But I need to apply changes before activity will be closed.

Any suggestions? **How to pass argument from child Activity to parent Fragment.**

P.S. Could **not** take parent fragment from `supportFragmentManager.fragments`

Comment: try childFragmentManager instead of supportFragmentManager

Comment: You can use [EventBus](https://greenrobot.org/eventbus/) to reflects your values, It will help you in this case.

Comment: Please try to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Why does the fragment need the data back early? It won't be running any code if it's paused.

Comment: You may want to use broadcaster instead.